# Use one instance of external module across Nestjs app

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I am importing a class from an external library to my NestJS app. I want to create one instance with a couple of environment variables and have that instance available to use across the whole application.

In a regular Node.js app, I would import the lib and initialize the instance in a separate module (file) and then just import it wherever I would need it.

What would be the best practice of doing this in NestJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use DI to solve the problem. So you need to define your class or service in some module and export it. Then you can have some custom logic defined for its creation in `providers` e.g.

```
{
    provide: SomeClass,
    useFactory: () => { ... }
}
```

You can have any custom logic in the `useFactory` to create an instance. Than once you import your module to other modules the same instance of a class will be available.

UPD: You can read more about custom providers here https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#factory-providers-usefactory